# t-test for two random variables

Tags: self-study, t-test

If I want to compare two random variables $X$ and $Y$ both normally distributed with mean 0.4, and 0.3 respectively; and standard deviation 0.05 and 0.04 respectively, what is the p-value that $X > Y$?

Comment: you seem to be confused about terminology. If you're calculating p-values you're dealing with samples (observations on random variables), rather than the random variables themselves, and you can't calculate a p-value without a sample size for each sample.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking. I'll try showing you a couple of
applications of t tests and the resulting P-values.
In order to do a t test comparing two populations, you need to have data.

Suppose you have $n = 100$ observations $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{100}$ from
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0.4, \sigma=0.05).$ Also $n = 100$ observations $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_{100}$ from
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0.3, \sigma=0.04).$ Data simulated using R:

```
set.seed(915)
x = rnorm(100, .4, .05);  y = rnorm(100, .3, .04)
all = c(x,y);  gp = rep(1:2, each=100)
stripchart(all ~ gp, ylim=c(.5,2.5), pch="|")
```

In the plot below, it certainly looks as if the $X_i$'s (bottom) tend to
be larger than the $Y_i$s.

[image]

Then you could do a two-sample t test $H_0: \mu_x = \mu_y$
against $H_a: \mu_x > \mu_y$. Because we know the variances are not equal,
we should do the Welch version of the t test.

```
t.test(all ~ gp, alt="greater")  # alternate equiv code: 't.test(x,y,alt="g")'

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  all by gp
t = 17.153, df = 185.85, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is greater than 0
 95 percent confidence interval:
 0.09360939        Inf
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
      0.3991712       0.2955782
```

In this *particular case* the P-value is $2.2 \times 10^{16},$ showing
very strong evidence that the sample means $\bar X = 0.399$ is significantly larger than $\bar Y = 0.296.$

The exact P-value will depend
on (a) the sample size and (b) the luck of the draw in taking the two samples from
their respective distributions.

You might want to know the *average* P-value for two samples each of size $n = 10.$ P-values will be larger for small samples. We could do a simulation to
find out the the average P-value for many samples of size 20.

```
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(10,.4,.05), rnorm(10,.3,.04),alt="g")$p.val)
mean(pv);  mean(pv < .05)
[1] 0.000800402
[1] 0.99908
```

Even with this smaller sample size, the average P-value is 0.0008, and such
two-sample tests will reject $H_0$ 99.9% of the time.

Without data or hypothesis testing, we can show that values of $X$ tend to be
larger than values of $Y$ by plotting the CDFs of their respective distributions.

[image]

If you had something else in mind, please edit your question to clarify.
But remember that P-values refer to tests of hypotheses, and tests require data.